# iphone Xcode settings problems

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am going through the Apple provisioning profile walkthrough documentation to create the binary to submit to the app store but came across a very visible problem.

The documentation shows that when the user clicks on the "Overview" tab in Xcode they should have a list of options such as:

Device - iPhone OS 2.0,
Device - iPhone OS 2.1,
Device - iPhone OS 2.2 (Project Settings),
Simulator - iPhone OS 2.0,
Simulator - iPhone OS 2.1,
Simulator - iPhone OS 2.2

However, in my version of Xcode, the "Overview" tab brings up this:

Device,
Simulator

I am wondering if this could possibly be contributing to the reason that the app store will not accept my binary - the error stating that "Apple is not currently accepting apps built in this version of the OS." Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

EDIT:I have checked everything that I can possibly think of - this is the final SDK 4.0 that is the most current.  I have tried almost every combination of base SDK and target SDK that is allowed in the build menu - although I am pretty sure the correct way is to have the base SDK at 4.0 and the target SDK at the lowest that it would possibly work - none of this works.  Is there some sort of help desk I can call at Apple because I have been working on this one tiny problem now for about 10 hours and I am not making any progress at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Must have been some recent changes to xcode.  Everything worked once I set the Base SDK to 4.0 and the target SDK to 3.2.

Answer (score 1):

Seams that you have and old SDK, try to download SDK4 final (not the beta).
Or your compiling options are old, to edit them right click on the project icon in the left column and click "Get info".
In the second tab (build) you should find all the options you need.

Comment: It says that I have version Xcode (3.2.3) in my Xcode about settings and then for the SDKs it says iPhone 3.2 and iPhone 4.0.

Under the Get info section of the project in the Build tab I have the Base SDK set to iPhone 4.0.  How can I tell if I have the 4.0 FINAL version or the Beta version?